# Visual Studio Code with C/C++ extension includePath not working?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, include, include-path

I'm beginner and i don't know which folder to include, when i type #include  it has red line under it, and it say's add path to settings.

I have installed the official C/C++ extension by Microsoft.

So here's my path settings:

```
 {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceRoot}",
            "C:/cygwin64/usr/include",
            "C:/cygwin64/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.4.0/include/c++"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE"
        ],
        "browse": {
            "path": [],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
        }
    }
```

I tried saving everything and then i restarted Visual Studio Code, it didn't work.

I tried adding multiple paths to that path setting list but, it still has red underline, when i use #include .

I also took look at Microsoft tutorial, but it didn't help and i can't find help anywhere else.

I would appreciate, if you could give me step by step instructions on this, because i'm very new to c++ development.

I only have one file and here's the code:

```
   #include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the cpp files which has #include lines that cause errors ? Would like to know what you want to include ...

Comment: I only have one simple hello.cpp file #include <iostream>
  
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

Comment: This is really opinion-based, but for beginner it would be better to install something that works out-of-box (such as Visual Studio 2017 Community edition with c++ rigging) than mess with setting up cygwin-based compilation (which may be rather not trivial).

Comment: I will definitely take look at it, but if someone sees this question and knows whats the problem please give suggestions so it could help other's too, i know a lot of people have the same problem, but the official Microsoft documentation is incomplete and not for beginner's.